# How do know that mysql table is partitioned?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

How do know that mysql table is partitioned? Is there any command which shows me how many partition my table?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this on your mysql:

```
 SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%partition%';
```

It will give you the value YES or NO. But to find the partitions for a particular table use this:

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT * FROM table;
```

Comment: any Idea for SQL server ?

Comment: @AshutoshArya This may be helpful, try the query explained in this link http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/query-which-tables-are-partitioned